# Another distinct and limit mysql

Tags: mysql, distinct, limit

The following does what it supposed to
it returns 200+ distinct records w/o the "limit 2"

What I want is to return 2 distinct records, but it stops after the 1st 2 records, meaning I only get 2 records

```
select distinct LEFT(`name`, LOCATE("(", `name`)-1), user_id, id
from ppbv79_listings
where  user_id = 3798 and category_id = 30 
group by LEFT(`name`, LOCATE("(", `name`)-1)
limit  2

Name                              user_id   id
Germany 1213 Used Carl Sonnenschein 3798    2160555 
Germany 1213 Used Carl Sonnenschein 3798    2160556
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You want to return two records, the code is returning two records.  Your question is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: You don't need to use `DISTINCT` when you use `GROUP BY`. There can't be any duplicates.

Comment: Data with limit 2 Germany 1213 Used Carl Sonnenschein  3798 2160555
Germany 1213 Used Carl Sonnenschein  3798 2160556

Comment: Put the clarifications in the quesiton, not comments, so you can format it nicely.

Comment: @Barmar OK, that works until I add limit, then I only get 2 records

Comment: That's what `LIMIT 2` means: return at most 2 records.

Comment: @Barmar, ok I'm looking for something like Top 2

Comment: @Barmar, the left func returns part of a string that looks like "this is the string" from name that looks like "this is the string (B123)", what I am doing is stripping out the "(B123)" from all records, making the left string indistinct

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to the entire select list, not just one column.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is how you make specific columns distinct, by aggregating all the rows with the same value in that column.

Comment: If you want `TOP 2` you should add `ORDER BY` to specify how you want the results ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select A.`trimmedName`,  A.user_id, A.id 
from
(select LEFT(`name`, LOCATE("(", `name`)-1) 
             `trimmedName`, user_id, id,count(category_id) `count`
 from ppbv79_listings
 where  user_id = 3798 and category_id = 30 
 group by LEFT(`name`, LOCATE("(", `name`)-1), user_id, id 
 order by `count` desc) A
 limit  2;
```

I assume there are some repetitions you would want to removed, and fetch the just the top 2 rows of data that repeats most.